# Global vs local resource conflicting location instructions within a bundle?

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, resources, bundle

I am confused about what seem to be conflicting instructions about whether to include localized vs global resources within an iOS bundle. In the "Bundle Structures" section of the "Bundle Programming Guide", it states (bold for emphasis):

> An iOS application should be internationalized and have a language.lproj folder for each language it supports. In addition to providing localized versions of your application’s custom resources, you can also localize your launch images by placing files with the same name in your language-specific project directories. **Even if you provide localized versions, however, you should always include a default version of these files at the top-level of your application bundle**. The default version is used in situations where a specific localization is not available.

That leads me to believe that I should have both a global resource for those resources that aren't localized for a given language and/or region. However, in the *same* programming guide as well as the `Bundle` Foundation documentation, it states:

> Because global resources take precedence over language-specific resources, **you should never include both a global and localized version of a given resource in your app**. When a global version of a resource exists, language-specific versions are never returned. The reason for this precedence is performance. If localized resources were searched first, the bundle object might waste time searching for a nonexistent localized resource before returning the global resource.

These statements seem to directly contradict each other. Can someone shed some light on what I'm missing here?